# JavaFX fxml loader does not work properly

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, loader

testFX.java :

```
public class testFX extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try{
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/testFX/view/test.fxml"));
            System.out.println("after set location");
            //PROBLEM
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)loader.load();
            System.out.println("Does not happen");
            testFXController listController = loader.getController();
            listController.start();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 300);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

testFXController.java :

```
package testFX.view;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class testFXController {
    @FXML ListView<String> listView;
    private ObservableList<String> obsList;

    public void start() {
        // create an ObservableList
        // from an ArrayList
        obsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Giants", "Patriots", "Jaguars");
        listView.setItems(obsList);
    }
}
```

test.fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="view.testFXController">
    <ListView fx:id="listView" 
        AnchorPane.topAnchor="10"
        AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10" 
        AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10"
        AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10" />
</AnchorPane>
```

When I run the testFX.java, the system prints:

```
after set location  
Error
```

This is the professor's code and I cannot seem to get it running. I realized that the main problem is in the line of code `AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)loader.load();` but I have no idea how to fix this, can someone help?

Comment: Display the whole stack trace instead of printing the message "Error"

Comment: Please replace `System.out.println("Error");` with `e.printStackTrace()`. Then run the program again and tell us the output.

Answer (score 1):

The value `fx:controller` attribute is most likely wrong (unless you have a different controller class than the one posted)

The controller you want to use: `testFX.view.testFXController`

Attribute value in the fxml: `view.testFXController` != `testFX.view.testFXController`

Assuming there is no other error that cannot be reproduced with the information in the question, fixing the attribute value should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `fx:controller` attribute within the fxml file is the culprit here.

`fx:controller="application.Controller"` worked for me.

Therefore, `fx:controller="testFX.view.testFXController"` should work for you.